# Where to report Gmail problems?

Tags: gmail, google

my gmail address is acting really strangely, it doesn't receive emails from certain email addresses, even though some emails get through. I've checked filters, SPAM, all folders - no problem there. It really seems to be problem on Google's side. But there is no way how to tell Google about this problem and maybe receive some reply about this.

Is there some special webform or address where I can report problems and get real answers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can contact them via the Google forum on [this page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail).

The google team **is** actually reading this forum and will intervene if needed within your account. They will contact you more deeply if needed.

Comment: Note: this link is now showing no content.

Comment: I updated it to a working link, but the [other answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37691) may be a more direct route nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

Gmail has now been integrated (and has been for some time) into the Google Feedback tool.

To get to this tool, go into your Gmail inbox, and click on the Gear (Settings).

Select "Send Feedback" and the Feedback tool will allow you to describe your problem and highlight/censor certain parts of a screenshot.

Comment: Add a screen shot of the "Send Feedback" option.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to apply to the current iteration of the gmail interface (April 2021). There is no "send feedback" available directly under the "Gear (settings)". (nor can I find it elsewhere)

Comment: Update: the option has moved to the "(?)" (help) menu to the left of the "gear" (settings) menu