# How would I report a problem to Google in situations where there is no link to their Feedback System?

Tags: google, google-feedback

Suppose I find a broken sentence, or a feature that is not working. Is there a way to report this to Google in situations where there is no link to [their Feedback System](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/)?

Can you describe briefly what I can and cannot do if I want to send a feedback message to Google?

Comment: Related: [Where to report Gmail problems?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24238)

Comment: I think it will largely depend on which product that has the issue.

Comment: In my specific case, it is in 2-step verification. The screen asks me to double-check my phone number and so forth. It says "On , you updated your settings to blah blah..." Well, I would assume that there is a missing date right after the word On, so I was going to send them a screen shot, but there is no where to send it. I was not keen on making this a product-specific question though, as I feel that a single answer would be able to cover most of Google's products pretty well. There does seem to be some consistency.

Comment: mostly respective google groups would tackle this issue you can directly post it to their respective team

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the product which you want to report, so it can be read by the right people who're actually dealing with it.

**YouTube**

For example on YouTube in footer menu you can click Help and Send feedback, which will open you feedback form and you can report anything including highlight areas of the page relevant to your feedback.

If you'd like to report any complaint (spam, legal issues, etc.), use [Reporting tool](https://www.youtube.com/reportingtool/). Otherwise check [Contact Us](https://www.youtube.com/t/contact_us) page for more contact details.

Otherwise, if you're looking for help, please use [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube).

**Gmail**

If you're using Gmail, you may use Google Feedback tool found in Settings (gear icon) and select Send Feedback. Otherwise use [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail).

See: [Where to report Gmail problems?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24238/where-to-report-gmail-problems)

**All Google Products**

If you're using any specific software, first of all look for options there.

Then in general, it's advised to use [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/) (similar like Apple), so you can get the help faster from community. And if your problem persist or it would be on Google side, then your issue would be redirected to the right people from there (similar as in Apple forum, I guess).

If you'd like to report the problem directly to Google for any specific product, go to [Google Contact Us](http://www.google.com/contact/) page and select from the dropdown menu the google product of interest. Then usually you'll have proper links to Contact Us or Forum to report the appropriate problem (or when asked if some article is useful, say it no, you'll be shown another form to send a feedback).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Google web application look for a question mark, cog or "hamburger" button. In some cases the option to send feedback is on the first level but on other you should have to look for a submenu.

If there isn't any of them, look at the bottom of the webpage for a "Help", "Send feedback", "Report a problem" or "Contact us" link.

Alternatively go to https://support.google.com?hl=en. Go to the help center of the corresponding product. Some of them have a Contact Us button at the top right corner, some have a help article with instructions about hot to contact a specialist of the product or from the sales team.

If you don't find your the specific help center for the specific product or feature look for one that has the strongest relationship. In case of 2SV, go to the Gmail Help Forum.

"Lastly" go to https://www.google.com/contact